# How to avoid scrapy UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I have the following code in my `parse_item` callback:

```
sel = Selector(response)
item['name'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="productDescriptionBlock"]/h2/text()').extract()[0]
return item
```

But I get `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\uff01' in position 271761: character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tried adding `.encode('utf-8')` but still get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 638, in _tick
    taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 484, in _oneWorkUnit
    result = next(self._iterator)
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
    work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py", line 23, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py", line 73, in _parse_response
    for request_or_item in self._requests_to_follow(response):
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py", line 52, in _requests_to_follow
    links = [l for l in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response) if l not in seen]
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/linkextractors/sgml.py", line 124, in extract_links
    ).encode(response.encoding)
  File "/home/scraper/.fakeroot/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x99' in position 349751: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of your exception?

Comment: Your updated error looks as if the site you are scraping is reporting the wrong encoding (the HTTP headers in the response tell you what codec to use, and `response.encoding` is that value).

Comment: We'll have to see if someone with specific Scrapy knowledge can provide a work-around for such sites.

Comment: The site has this in the meta tags. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Sure, but I *think* the `response.encoding` attribute reflects the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=....` value.

Comment: Okay, looks like it. The Content-Type is set to "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before. If I'm not wrong, you are using the `restrict_xpaths` parameter in your rule's link extractor.

Possible solutions are:

1. Avoid to use `restrict_xpaths` for that particular site. This happens because the page content contains characters not defined in the declared encoding.
2. Identify the invalid characters and replace them before the rule acts on it. This can be tricky, though.
3. Use the middleware in this answer to re-encode the response into its declared encoding:  [UnicodeEncodeError after setting restrict_xpaths settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595359/unicodeencodeerror-after-setting-restrict-xpaths-settings/19602304#19602304)